# Working of gearbox in driving simulators

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, automotive-engineering, simulation

I am a newbie in this field.

Please help me in gaining a bit initial fundamental knowledge in simple language.

How are gearbox ratios interpreted in driving simulators? Are the gearboxes used in driving simulators the same as in normal manual transmission cars?

How are the gear change signals from the gear levers and the gearbox   sent to the simulator electronic systems or  screens?

What is attached to the gearbox in those driving simulators?

Comment: What do you mean by "interpreted"?

Comment: final drive ratios are used in conjunction with an engine's power/torque curve to determine acceleration of the vehicle.  No one is modeling a gear train in software.

Comment: Could you give an example (or several) of a "driving simulator"?